# Primefaces file download only works when I use the default constructor

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I download a file using HttpURLConnection, then I want to give the user the option to download that file. I use this primefaces example http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml.

My issue is that if I download hard coded file via the default constructor as it's mentioned in the example, everything work. but if  I pass the filename to constructor that accept param, I get a null pointer.

Here is the code with both constructor (only the default constructor with the hard coded file works)

```
@ManagedBean

public class FileDownloadView {

    private StreamedContent file;
    private InputStream stream;
    private String fileName;

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }


    public FileDownloadView() {
        InputStream stream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/tmp/1kb.txt");
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "text/plain", "text.txt");
        System.out.println("fileName......." + "test.txt");

    }

    public  FileDownloadView(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;

        InputStream stream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/tmp/" + fileName);
        this.fileName = fileName;
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "text/plain", fileName);
        System.out.println("fileName......." + file.getName());

    }

    public StreamedContent getFile() {
        System.out.println("file  "+file.getName());

        return file;
    }
}
```

And here how I am pulling the file

```
     <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s">
                <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}" />
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:outputLabel value="#{fileDownloadView.fileName}"/>
        </h:form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                                       function start() {
                                           PF('statusDialog').show();
                                       }

                                       function stop() {
                                           PF('statusDialog').hide();
                                       }
        </script>
```

Comment: Who is going to call the constructor? Not JSF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [f:attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/attribute.html) to pass the file name from your UI to the controller and call the download.

According to the tag's definition, **it provides an option to pass an attribute's value to a component, or a parameter to a component via action listener.**

So In your case you wanted to pass the fileName to the controller and download the file accordingly.

```
    <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="true" actionListener="#{fileDownloadView.prepareToDownload}" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s">
                <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}" />
                <f:attribute name="fileName" value="#{fileDownloadView.fileName}" />
   </p:commandButton>
```

OR

```
<h:commandLink id="downloadLink"
    title="Download"
    actionListener="#{fileDownloadView.prepareToDownload}">
    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/common/images/download.gif"
        alt="Download" />
        <f:attribute name="fileName" value="#{fileDownloadView.fileName}" />
        <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

In your controller write the actionEvent and manage your download.

```
public void prepareToDownload(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        String fileName = (String)actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("fileName");
        InputStream stream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/tmp/" + fileName);
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "text/plain", fileName);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand this line <f:attribute name="fileName" value="#{edi.ediOid}" /> can you provide a little more detail please? I changed viewEDI with my controller name. but not sure how to work with f:attribute

Comment: Sorry. I have copy pasted the code which I am using in my projectv. Now I have updated my answer.  You can try the same.

Comment: Thanks detailed explanation, I posted another question about why the button not firing within a Datatable. but it works if it's not in a data table. Let me know if you can take a look. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must not create a second constructor in a class with the annotation `@ManagedBean` to initialize the filename variable.

Comment: So, what is the solution to my problem. How to accomplish my task? download a file by passing a parameter?

Answer (score -1):

You could try this

```
@ManagedBean
public class FileDownloadView {

private StreamedContent file;
private InputStream stream;
private String fileName = "error";

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
public void setFileName(String _filename) {
    this.fileName = _fileName;
}
public FileDownloadView() {

}
```

The method prepareToDownload allows managing file downloads . It is in this way that we can recover the file name .

```
public void prepareToDownload(ActionEvent actionEvent){
    setFileName((String)actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("fileName"));
    InputStream stream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/tmp/" + fileName);
    setFile( new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "text/plain", fileName));
}
public StreamedContent getFile() {
    System.out.println("file  "+file.getName());

    return file;
}
public void setFile(StreamedContent _file) {
    this.file  = _file;

}
}
}
```

And then in your xhtml file:

```
<h:commandLink id="downloadLink"
title="Download"
actionListener="#{fileDownloadView.prepareToDownload}">
<p:graphicImage value="/resources/common/images/download.gif"
    alt="Download" />
    <f:attribute name="fileName" value="#{fileDownloadView.fileName}" />
    <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}" />
</h:commandLink>
<h:outputText value="#{fileDownloadView.fileName}"/>
```